# Hikari for High Availability DBs - Auto failover

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a Java Springboot application that uses Hikari to create & manage database connections. I have 2 oracle databases - one is the primary and the other secondary (used in case primary fails).

Is there a way to configure an automatic switch over from primary to secondary in case primary DB goes down , in Hikari ?

Comment: Isn't that something the oracle JDBC driver should do for you and that you should only provide the proper configuration for this. Not sure why this would be an Hikari problem.

Comment: Apologies. Am a newbie to this whole Hikari based solution. I was under the impression that Hikari would be responsible for what MDS is for Weblogic.